# Integrate $\tan^2(\frac{\pi}{12} \cdot y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, complex-integration

Integrate $\tan^2(\frac{\pi}{12} \cdot y)$

[Wolfram gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20tan%5E2%28pi%2F12%20y%29) the answer:

$$\frac{12 \tan(\frac{\pi y}{12})}{\pi} -y + \text{constant}$$

But why is the value of $\tan^2$ not getting differentiated?
According to [this rule](http://www.math-prof.com/Calculus_2/Ch07_04.jpg), the answer should be:

$$\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{12} \cdot y)}{\frac{\pi}{12} \cdot (2-1)}$$

($\dfrac{\pi}{12}$ is a constant so it's not differentiated)

Also, what is meant by aX? In my case, what's my "aX"? $\frac{\pi}{12} \cdot y$? So does the "a" simply means what's before the variable y? $\frac{\pi}{12}$?

Comment: the rule doesn't tell you to integrate the argument of the tan function, but it does tell you to integrate the $tan^{(0)}$ function ( which equals 1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y=t\implies \frac{\pi}{12}dy=dt\iff dy=\frac{12}{\pi}dt$

We have $$\int \tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y\right)dy=\int \tan^2 (t) \frac{12}{\pi}dt$$ $$=\frac{12}{\pi}\int \tan^2(t)dt$$
$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\int (\sec^2(t)-1)dt$$
$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\int\sec^2(t)dt-\frac{12}{\pi}\int dt$$
$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\tan(t)-\frac{12}{\pi}\cdot t+C$$
Setting $t=\frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y$
$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y\right)-\frac{12}{\pi}\cdot \frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y+C$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{12}{\pi}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\cdot y\right)-y+C}$$

Comment: how did -1 turn into - $\frac{12}{\pi}$?

Answer (score 1):

While the rule 
$$\int \tan^n axdx = \frac{\tan^{n-1} ax}{a(n-1)} - \int \tan^{n-2}axdx$$
may superficially look as if it was derived by integrating by parts, it wasn't. We simply substitute $\sec^2 ax - 1$ for $\tan ^2ax$
$$\int \tan^n axdx = \int \tan^2ax\tan^{n-2} axdx=\int(\sec^2ax-1)\tan^{n-2}axdx$$
$$=\int\sec^2ax\tan^{n-2}axdx -\int\tan^{n-2}axdx$$
The first part is easily integrated by substituting $u=\tan ax\implies dx = \frac{du}{a\cdot\sec^2 ax}$
$$=\int\frac{u^{n-2}}{a}du - \int\tan^{n-2}axdx=\frac{u^{n-1}}{a(n-1)}-\int\tan^{n-2}axdx+C$$
$$=\frac{\tan^{n-1}ax}{a(n-1)}-\int\tan^{n-2}axdx+C$$

Applying the rule gives,
$$\int \tan^2\bigg(\frac{\pi}{12}y\bigg)dy=\frac{\tan^1ax}{\frac{\pi}{12}(2-1)}-\int\tan^0axdx=\frac{12}{\pi}\tan ax - \int dy$$
$$=\frac{12}{\pi}\tan ax - y+C$$

One final word, saying things like "what's before the variable y" is the first step to *memorization mayhem*. $a$ does not come before $y$, but rather, $a$ is multiplied by the variable of integration
$$\text{e.g.}\int \tan^n (ax)dx = \int\tan^n(x\cdot a) dx$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you should forget about those integrating rules. It is better to learn techniques.

I think you have two problems here:

**1) to find a primitive function of $\tan^2 y$.**

Here I suggest that you recall the differentiation rule
$$
D\tan y=1+\tan^2y.
$$
It implies directly that
$$
\int \tan^2y\,dy=\int (1+\tan^2y)-1\,dy=\tan y-y.
$$

**2) What happens with a primitive when scaling the argument.**

In general if $F$ is a primitive function to $f$ (that is $\int f(y)\,dy=F(y)+C$, and $a\neq 0$,
$$
\int f(a y)\,dy = \frac{1}{a}F(ay).
$$

So, in your case $f(y)=\tan^2y$, and $a=\pi/12$, so
$$
\int \tan^2(\pi y/12)\,dy=\frac{1}{\pi/12}\bigl(\tan (\pi y/12)-\pi y/12\bigr)=\frac{12\tan(\pi y/12)}{\pi}-y.
$$

Of course, one could add a $C$ in the end to get all primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\int \tan^2 x\ dx = \int {\sin^2 x \over 1 - \sin^2 x} dx = -x + \tan x$, we find:

$\int \tan^2 \left( {\pi y \over 12} \right) d y = \frac{12 \tan \left(\frac{\pi  y}{12}\right)}{\pi }-y$

Comment: yeah, I assumed you're supposed to differentiate what's inside the tangent value, turns out you leave it as it is in the numerator... also, your answer still doesn't show how you arrive at the solution, or at least say what rule/formula is used... cuz you divide by $\pi$ there...